# How can I fix "uuid/uuid.h - No such file" error in CentOS

Tags: centos, uuid

I am running CentOS 7 (64 bit). I am trying to build a project and I am getting this error.

```
fatal error: uuid/uuid.h: No such file or directory
 #include <uuid/uuid.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Is this related to a missing package? I have already installed uuid-devel. What package should I install to fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I was missing the same while trying to compile Syslinux for aarch64.

Answer (score 25):

Installing the development package libuuid-devel as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109370/creating-softlinks-to-header-files-that-are-not-in-the-expected-directory), fixed the issue.

```
sudo yum install libuuid libuuid-devel
```

Comment: It is `libuuid-devel`, not `libuuid-devl`

Comment: what about old centos 5?

Comment: The suggested solution works; dear OP, please mark it as "accepted", or justify why you haven't done so yet.

Comment: This works. Hit this bug when trying to build rpms for mod_gearman on Centos 7

Comment: For those coming here with a similar problem in Ubuntu, `apt-get install uuid-dev` is what you want.